# Return count of register that was updated in less than 15 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time building a query that returns results according to the following requirements:

- return all records where account_service is the same for the current day
- Check which records have an interval of less than 15 minutes in the `updated` column
- return the count grouped by user

It is difficult to explain the logic, I think that is why I am having difficulty building the query .. basically I want to return recurring records, where the recurrence is determined by the 15 minute interval. If there is a record for another user with the same account_service within 15 minutes, then +1 is added to the counter

Reproducable example
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/osBDjeLexDRdj2T1aNZb2c/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `account_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `table_` (`id`, `user`, `account_service`, `created`, `updated`) VALUES
(1, 'user1', '123', '2021-04-19 20:29:30', '2021-04-19 00:00:00'),
(2, 'user1', '321', '2021-04-19 20:29:30', '2021-04-19 00:00:00'),
(3, 'user2', '123', '2021-04-19 20:29:45', '2021-04-19 00:15:00'),
(4, 'user2', '321', '2021-04-19 20:29:45', '2021-04-19 00:15:00'),
(5, 'user3', '321', '2021-04-19 20:29:45', '2021-04-19 00:27:00');
```

required output

```
+-------+-------+
| user  | count |
+-------+-------+
| user1 |     2 |
| user2 |     1 |
| user3 |     0 |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: what does the count in the result mean? e.g. why is count = 0 for user3 and 1 for user2?

Comment: means the number of records that were entered by another user and that contain the same account_service and that the creation date is within 15 minutes of the update date

Comment: your explanation doesn't reflect what you showed us a desired output , try to explain the logic better

Comment: It is difficult to explain the logic, I think that is why I am having difficulty building the query .. basically I want to return recurring records, where the recurrence is determined by the 15 minute interval. If there is a record for another user with the same account_service within 15 minutes, then +1 is added to the counter

Comment: then why is the count = 0 for user3, considering that both user1 and user2 have the same account_service and are within 15 minutes?